# ValueError while using linear SVM of scikit-learn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am currently working on large scale hierarchical text classification of ODP documents. The dataset provided to me is in the libSVM format. I am trying to run the linear kernel SVM of python's scikit-learn to develop the model. Below is the sample data from training samples:

```
29 9454:1 11742:1 18884:14 26840:1 35147:1 52782:1 72083:1 73244:1 78945:1 79913:1 79986:1 86710:3 117286:1 139820:1 142458:1 146315:1 151005:2 161454:3 172237:1 1091130:1 1113562:1 1133451:1 1139046:1 1157534:1 1180618:2 1182024:1 1187711:1 1194345:3 

33 2474:1 8152:1 19529:2 35038:1 48104:1 59738:1 61854:3 67943:1 74093:1 78945:1 88558:1 90848:1 97087:1 113284:16 118917:1 122375:1 124939:1
```

The following is the code I have used to construct the linear SVM model

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
from sklearn import svm
X_train, y_train = load_svmlight_file("/path-to-file/train.txt")
X_test, y_test = load_svmlight_file("/path-to-file/test.txt")
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print clf.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Upon running clf.score(), I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b285fbfb3efe> in <module>()
      1 start_time = time.time()
----> 2 print clf.score(X_test,y_test)
      3 print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"

/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.pyc in score(self, X, y)
    292         """
    293         from .metrics import accuracy_score
--> 294         return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X))
    295 
    296 

/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    464             Class labels for samples in X.
    465         """
--> 466         y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
    467         return self.classes_.take(y.astype(np.int))
    468 

/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    280         y_pred : array, shape (n_samples,)
    281         """
--> 282         X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
    283         predict = self._sparse_predict if self._sparse else self._dense_predict
    284         return predict(X)

/Users/abc/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in _validate_for_predict(self, X)
    402             raise ValueError("X.shape[1] = %d should be equal to %d, "
    403                              "the number of features at training time" %
--> 404                              (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
    405         return X
    406 

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1199847 should be equal to 1199830, the number of features at training time
```

Can someone please let me know what is exactly wrong with either this code or the piece of data I have? Thanks in advance

Below attached are the values of X_train, y_train, X_test, and y_test:

X_train:

```
  (0, 9453)         1.0
  (0, 11741)    1.0
  (0, 18883)    14.0
  (0, 26839)    1.0
  (0, 35146)    1.0
  (0, 52781)    1.0
  (0, 72082)    1.0
  (0, 73243)    1.0
  (0, 78944)    1.0
  (0, 79912)    1.0
  (0, 79985)    1.0
  (0, 86709)    3.0
  (0, 117285)   1.0
  (0, 139819)   1.0
  (0, 142457)   1.0
  (0, 146314)   1.0
  (0, 151004)   2.0
  (0, 161453)   3.0
  (0, 172236)   1.0
  (0, 187531)   2.0
  (0, 202462)   1.0
  (0, 210417)   1.0
  (0, 250581)   1.0
  (0, 251689)   1.0
  (0, 296384)   2.0
  : :
  (4462, 735469)    1.0
  (4462, 737059)    15.0
  (4462, 740127)    1.0
  (4462, 743798)    1.0
  (4462, 766063)    1.0
  (4462, 778958)    2.0
  (4462, 784004)    4.0
  (4462, 837264)    2.0
  (4462, 839095)    22.0
  (4462, 844735)    6.0
  (4462, 859721)    2.0
  (4462, 875267)    1.0
  (4462, 910761)    1.0
  (4462, 931244)    1.0
  (4462, 945069)    6.0
  (4462, 948728)    1.0
  (4462, 948850)    2.0
  (4462, 957682)    1.0
  (4462, 975170)    1.0
  (4462, 989192)    1.0
  (4462, 1014294)   1.0
  (4462, 1042424)   1.0
  (4462, 1049027)   1.0
  (4462, 1072931)   1.0
  (4462, 1145790)   1.0
```

y_train:

```
[  2.90000000e+01   3.30000000e+01   3.30000000e+01 ...,   1.65475000e+05
   1.65518000e+05   1.65518000e+05]
```

X_test:

```
  (0, 18573)    1.0
  (0, 23501)    1.0
  (0, 29954)    1.0
  (0, 42112)    1.0
  (0, 46402)    1.0
  (0, 63041)    2.0
  (0, 67942)    2.0
  (0, 83522)    1.0
  (0, 88413)    2.0
  (0, 99454)    1.0
  (0, 126041)   1.0
  (0, 139819)   1.0
  (0, 142678)   1.0
  (0, 151004)   1.0
  (0, 166351)   2.0
  (0, 173794)   1.0
  (0, 192162)   3.0
  (0, 210417)   2.0
  (0, 254468)   1.0
  (0, 263895)   2.0
  (0, 277567)   1.0
  (0, 278419)   2.0
  (0, 279181)   2.0
  (0, 281319)   2.0
  (0, 298898)   1.0
  : :
  (1857, 1100504)   3.0
  (1857, 1103247)   1.0
  (1857, 1105578)   1.0
  (1857, 1108986)   2.0
  (1857, 1118486)   1.0
  (1857, 1120807)   9.0
  (1857, 1129243)   2.0
  (1857, 1131786)   1.0
  (1857, 1134029)   2.0
  (1857, 1134410)   5.0
  (1857, 1134494)   1.0
  (1857, 1139045)   25.0
  (1857, 1142239)   3.0
  (1857, 1142651)   1.0
  (1857, 1144787)   1.0
  (1857, 1151891)   1.0
  (1857, 1152094)   1.0
  (1857, 1157533)   1.0
  (1857, 1159376)   1.0
  (1857, 1178944)   1.0
  (1857, 1181310)   2.0
  (1857, 1182023)   1.0
  (1857, 1187098)   1.0
  (1857, 1194344)   2.0
  (1857, 1195819)   9.0
```

y_test:

```
[  2.90000000e+01   3.30000000e+01   1.56000000e+02 ...,   1.65434000e+05
   1.65475000e+05   1.65518000e+05]
```

Comment: Could you give the shapes of all your Xs and Ys ?

Comment: @tk I have updated my question to post the values.

Answer (score 8):

The error message

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1199847 should be equal to 1199830, the number of features at training time
```

explains itself: the number of features in the testing data is different compared to the training data, which has been used to train the model. That is, `X_train.shape[1]` is not equal to `X_test.shape[1]`.

You should check why they are not equal, as they should be.

One possibility is that they are loaded as sparse matrices and the number of features is inferred by [`load_svmlight_file`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html). If the testing data contains features unseen by the training data, the resulting `X_test` might have a larger dimension. To avoid this, you can specify the number of features in `load_svmlight_file` by passing the argument `n_features`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `n_features` option.

```
X_train, y_train = load_svmlight_file("/path-to-file/train.txt")
X_test, y_test = load_svmlight_file("/path-to-file/test.txt", n_features=X_train.shape[1])
```

This error also can be solved by using `load_svmlight_files`

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_files
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = load_svmlight_files(['/path-to-file/train.txt', '/path-to-file/test.txt'])
```

Answer (score 2):

`predict()` function requires value in 2d array, but `X_train.data[4]` is in 1d array. You can simply add array bracket (eg. `[X_train.data[4]]` ) to convert 1d array to 2d array

```
print(clf.predict([X_train.data[4]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found!!

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

1. The file should be encoding with utf-8
2. The data frame object should be reshaped. Like `X_train.values[4].reshape(1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case this is resolved by *deleting* the already created model. This could happen if you used *--fixed_model_name* option during training. Say the training data or data format (in my case, it is both - data AND md to json) changed ==> it creates the model without any issues BUT the rasa errors off with this message when we post a query.